# image processing with eclipse and opencv for android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

how can i do image processing with using openCV library and eclipse for android by selecting the image from file without cameraview? I tried the this code and i have an error java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    protected static final String TAG = null;


    private final String imageInSD1 = "/sdcard/dapi1.jpg";  
    //private final String imageInSD2 = "/sdcard/fitch1.jpg";   
    //private final String imageInSD3 = "/sdcard/txred1.jpg";   

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this){
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status){
            switch(status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"OpenCV loaded succesfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            }
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            }
        }
    };

     public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallBack);
        }

    private JavaCameraView mOpenCvCameraView;



    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD1);
        Size size = new Size(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        Mat src = new Mat(size,CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,src);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.threshold(src, src, 100, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C);
        Utils.matToBitmap(src, bitmap);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }



}
```

Error

> 08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 08-17 10:21:03.765:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   com.example.deneme4.MainActivity$1.onManagerConnected(MainActivity.java:41)
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1131)
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1148)
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800) 08-17
>   10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 08-17
>   10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 08-17 10:21:03.765:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405) 08-17
>   10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-17
>   10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 08-17 10:21:03.765:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
>   08-17 10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 08-17
>   10:21:03.765: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: you should check the stacktrace from the logcat and see in which line the Exception is thrown

Comment: i added error part , could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

see this part of the Exception stacktrace: `E/AndroidRuntime(1014): at com.example.deneme4.MainActivity$1.onManagerConnected(MainActivity.java:41) 08-17` it tells you in which line the Exception (41) was thrown and the name of the method name (MainActivity$1.onManagerConnected).

Looking at your onManagerConnected method it seems you are trying to call a method at an not initialized object here:

```
mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
```

To solve it, just initialize mOpenCvCameraView first.